# How to change modal

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using ui bootstrap v0.10 in my angular project. When I try to use the modal window, I can setup the width to a smaller size using the windowClass, however it changes also throws the window position to most right.

Can anyone help me?

the code that I'm using to try changing the width is as follows:

```
    $stateProvider.state("signin", {
        url: "/signin",
        onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'Pages/Modals/Signin.html',
                windowClass: 'fs-login-modal',
                controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.dismiss = function () {
                        $scope.$dismiss();
                    };
                }]
            }).result.then(function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    return $state.transitionTo("/");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My css class is setup as follows:
        login-modal {
        width:270px;
        }

Best regards,
Chen

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me right, add a negative margin-left of half the width.

```
.login-modal { 
  width:270px; 
  margin-left: -135px;
}
```

I remember it being a bit more complicated, maybe dealing with a .modal-inner class or something, but this should get you on the right track.